How to specify a non-npm dependency in GitHub?
I'm trying to use package.json to document the dependencies of my non-npm JavaScript project in GitHub.  Based on https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies, I've tried the following:
    "dependencies": {
        "hardhat": "^2.0.1",
        "hardhat-verify": "^2.0.2",
        "@nomicfoundation/hardhat": "^2.0.3",
        "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify": "^2.0.4",
        "@nomicfoundation/somethingelse": "^2.0.5",
        "hardhat6": "nomicfoundation/hardhat",
        "hardhat7": "nomicfoundation/hardhat#semver:^2.0.7",
        "hardhat8": "git+https://nomicfoundation@github.com/hardhat",
        "hardhat9": "git+https://nomicfoundation@github.com/hardhat#semver:^2.0.9"
    }

I would expect 1, 3, 6, 7, 8, and 9 to yield valid urls.  Instead, 1 and 4 are the only ones that do so (although 4 links to nomicfoundation/hardhat).  It seems like the only thing that actually succeeds is a valid npm project as the key and ending with a valid number (although why 4 and not 3 is confusing me).
Since my project is not npm, I have non-npm dependencies that I would like to include.  Primarily, this is to get a valid Software Bill of Materials, but it would also be nice to have the dependencies properly linked in my Insights tab (having Dependabot alerts would be great, but probably impractical since I've left the npm ecosystem).  Unfortunately, my SBOM includes, for example,
        {
            "SPDXID": "SPDXRef-npm-hardhat7",
            "name": "npm:hardhat7",
            "versionInfo": "^ 2.0.7",
            "downloadLocation": "NOASSERTION",
            "filesAnalyzed": false,
            "supplier": "NOASSERTION",
            "externalRefs": [
                {
                    "referenceCategory": "PACKAGE-MANAGER",
                    "referenceLocator": "pkg:npm/hardhat7",
                    "referenceType": "purl"
                }
            ]
        },

which appears to be trying to link to a non-existent npm package.  Is there a way to specify a (Git(Hub)) URL as a dependency for something that is in GitHub but isn't npm?  I've asked on GitHub discussions, but haven't had any responses.
